# How to make a Universal Binary out of two separate projects?

Tags: iphone, ipad, universal-binary

I have got an iPhone and an iPad app - both are separate fully working XCode projects. What I want to do is make a universal binary app out of these two. how can I do it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that projects using the same code it would be quite easy: just create new project, add sources and set Targeted device family to iPhone/iPad. However if you have separate code for each device, my congratulations, you'll have a big pain in the butt: you have to merge that sources and check for the device at runtime. Everything else is like in the first case.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, the code is different and the xibs, too. What to do with them (the xibs)?

Comment: You'll have to determine at runtime what device you are running and choose appropriate xib.

Comment: Just try to merge all your view controllers: ideally if you've designed your app correctly they should not differ (that's the power of MVC pattern).

Comment: So I have to do that in code, not just rename the files and add "-iPad" or something?

Comment: Yep. There are no documented suggestions about "-iPad".

Comment: =) it will encourage you to spend more time for architecture design in the future